# Ошибка при запуске приложения, считывающего данные из бд Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Всё хочу получить данные из Fb, но ничего не выходит.
На этот раз такой лог ошибок:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.jekak.fewfew, PID: 2291
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                  at com.example.jekak.fewfew.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:38)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
```

Вот это я увидел и сразу понял, что что-то не так с кодом, но понять что именно не так, что-то не получается. Вот сам код.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private List<String> KitchenMenu;
    ListView ListViewKitchenMenu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListViewKitchenMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.discr_for_list);

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //получение списка
                GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
                KitchenMenu = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);       
                updateUI(); //обновление новых данных
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, KitchenMenu);
        ListViewKitchenMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**build.gradle** тоже прикреплю

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jekak.fewfew"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Делал всё по видео, в видео всё считывается и нормально запускается. У меня - ошибки. В видео было с Authentication и данные получали по Uid, и поэтому не было ошибки с получением данных. Помогите в общем, пожалуйста.

p.s. скрин бд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас что-то со структурой данных. Вы пытаетесь парсить List (`GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};`), тогда как у вас по факту `HashMap`. Т.е. вам надо как-то так:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>() {};
Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
```

Comment: Подставил, ошибка  **com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String**. Сейчас скрин прилеплю сверху примера данных.

Comment: Попробуйте `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`

Comment: Всё равно ошибку выдаёт :(

Comment: Ту же самую?...

Comment: Даааа, преобразовать не может дабл

Comment: Вам надо или дабл на стринг заменить или писать в бд таки дабл, а не стринг

Comment: Можете пример данных точно привести и соответствующий код?

Comment: См ответ,........